# I can’t ping my router from the outer

Tags: router, ip, ping

I am trying to remote the server of my company from my home.

I enter the router of the company and I get this info:

```
Internet, IPv4
POST LuxFibre LAN1 NG, IP address: 10.244.149.239
```

But I also Google my IP address, and google tells me that my IP address is `88.207.251.1`

I am confused now.

For the LAN of my company, the IP of the router is something like `192.168.1.1`. So I consider that the `10.244.149.239` is the IP address of the router in outer net. But Google tells me that the outer IP is `88.207.251.1`. Why?

Besides, I cant ping `88.207.251.1` from outer but I can ping 10.244.149.239.

Why do I seem to have two outer IP addresses?

If I want to remote the server from my home or even from other countries, which IP should I use?

Comment: tbh, I'd just ask your IT department how to do it. Even if you managed to figure out your company's IP address [it's not 10.244.149.239 btw, that's in internal private IP, & so is 192.168.1.1] then it still would be unlikely to just let you in.

Comment: Why cant you find your IP of your office network using any online tools like  [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/) ?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath   I could. This tool tells me that my ip is 88.207.251.1. In fact i have already known this ip. But I cant ping it. I believe that u cant either.

Comment: @Thomas : From where did you get 10.244.149.239?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath   omg man. This is what i really dont understand. which one is my ip.....

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath I used no-ip service to get a domain name for my dynamic ip address. The tool tells me that my ip is 88.207.251.1, but when I bind this ip with the domain name, the ip changes into 10.244.149.239. I am confused now... Do u know why?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath   I enter into my router from the LAN of my company, and it tells me that the ip4 of my router is 10.244.149.239. But when I google, google tells me that my ip is 88.207.251.1. Is the 10.244.149.239 is a kind of inner ip address? If so, I am really confused because the inner ip address should be 192.168.1.1 right?

Comment: What is the result of ipconfig /all?

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath   this command can just see the inner ip right? it's 192.168.1.1. You see, this is where I dont understand. Now I have three IP address: 88.207.251.1  10.244.149.239  and 192.168.1.1......

Comment: @Thomas : You are making things unnecessarily confusing. your external IP is  88.207.251.1. Without having a knowledge of your network settings, it is impossible to provide you with a solution. Double check your network settings including firewall and proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

192.168.1.1 and 10.244.149.239 are internal addresses. They are not meant to be routed externally, so the connection you need to make is to your company's external interface IP address for remote access. This will need to be set up by your IT department, otherwise your connection is likely to be denied by the company's external firewall/router..

88.207.251.1 is the external address assigned to your router by your ISP. That router will also have an internal address, and your PC will have yet another address.

Every interface has to have an address in order to correctly route packets, so don't be confused if you see many.

Answer (score -2):

Thomas,

What the IP showed by google is a public IP, whereas the router gives you the private ip.

Secondly, you cannot ping your office router from your home, as the enterprise network/routers are always secure.

-Alan.

Comment: OK, I understand now. The router can't be ping.

Comment: "Always secure" seems like a strong phrase here..

Comment: I'd love to live in a world where office networks were always secure. Maybe not... Pesky job security.