# My external IP address appears to change automatically

Tags: router, dns, ip

I am trying to use the no-IP service to get a domain name for my dynamic ip address. I use some tools on line to detect my IP, and they tell me that my IP address is `88.207.251.1`. So I bind this IP with a domain name [at this website](http://www.noip.com/).

But to my surprise, it changes automatically!

I mean, when I try to ping my domain name, it becomes this ip:

```
10.244.149.239
```

And I go to  [that website](http://www.noip.com/) to check my domain name and i find that that IP changes into `10.244.149.239`.

I really dont know why.

Besides, I enter into my router and the router tells me that its IP address is `10.244.149.239`.

I don’t understand. The inner IP of the router—an [AVM FRITZ!Box 7490](http://www.fritzbox.com.au/product-fritz-wlan7490.html)—should be something like `192.168.1.1`? Because to enter into the router, I type 192.168.1.1 at the Internet Explorer.

- If the `10.244.149.239` is outer ip, what is `88.207.251.1`?
- If the `10.244.149.239` is inner ip, what is `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: You have double NAT. Your dynamic IP address is also private, so you can't map a domain name to it and accept incoming connections. What is your router connected to *exactly*?

Comment: Or, more generally: Please name your ISP and data plan.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  my router is "FRITZ!Box 7490"

Comment: @DanielB    my router is "FRITZ!Box 7490"

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://superuser.com/questions/897382/i-cant-ping-my-router-from-the-outer

Comment: What is your router connected to? Be as exact as you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.X.X.X is a Class A private network IP range. All values in here are always on a private network. Some routers utilize 192.168.X.X, a Class C private network IP range. You should always see one of these ranges as your "default gateway," unless you're directly connected to the internet. Most providers today are using NATs unless you request a static IP address. This means that your IP of 88.207.251.1 is probably shared with other "Entreprise des P&T" customers on your local node (possibly your neighborhood or city).

Using NAT allows service providers to provide many more customers service than they could using only their allocated IP addresses. Since the IPv4 space has been completely exhausted, such tricks are necessary to keep the Internet going while everyone upgrades to IPv6. Contact your service provider if you want a dedicated IP address, and expect to pay more for the service.